# React Native support PiP (Picture-in-Picture) mode for video calling app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, videocall, react-native-webrtc

I need to add PiP(Picture in Picture) mode to a react native app (both Android and iOS).
Some video calling apps such as Google Meet, etc are already support PiP mode, and I want to make the app like this. I'm using `react-native-webrtc` library for video calling feature and app works fine in foreground mode, but don't know how to add PiP mode to the app for both iOS and Android.

Thanks!